# Configure Dockerfile to set AWS configurations

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker

I've just started looking at `Docker`. I have a node app that resizes and image and then sends an `SQS` message to `aws` when finished. I have managed to create a docker image of my app, copying it from my local machine, but run into the issue that I can't set-up the `AWS` varibales that contain my `client_id` and `client_secret` to send the `SQS` message.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

What commands do I need to write in my `dockerfile` to have the `aws` variable set-up?

This is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#install node and npm
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install curl && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash - && \
    apt-get -y install python build-essential nodejs

#install imagemagick, graphicsmagick and set-up aws-cli to send SQS messages
RUN sudo apt-get -y install imagemagick
RUN sudo apt-get -y install graphicsmagick
RUN sudo apt-get install unzip
RUN curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
RUN unzip awscli-bundle.zip
RUN sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws

#set-up environment variables for AWS


#at some point set-up git and fetch repository from git


# Provides cached layer for node_modules
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /home/image-resizer && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /home/image-resizer/

#bundle source code into image
COPY . /home/image-resizer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answers regarding the environment variables are good solutions.  To offer an alternative, or if you use a file for aws authentication, you could use docker volumes to mount these.

> Mount a Host Directory as a Data Volume
>
> In addition to creating a volume using the -v flag you can also mount a directory from your Docker daemon's host into a container.
>
> Note: If you are using Boot2Docker, your Docker daemon only has limited access to your OSX/Windows filesystem. Boot2Docker tries to auto-share your /Users (OSX) or C:\Users (Windows) directory - and so you can mount files or directories using docker run -v /Users/:/ ... (OSX) or docker run -v /c/Users/:/

Taken from https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

This solution has the draw back of assuming that the config folder is in a fixed location however.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ENV** to set up your environment variable in docker. For example.

```
ENV PORT=9000
ENV LANG=en_US.utf8
```

However, secret information should not embedded in Dockerfile, you can pass with **-e** parameter or using a text file and pass to docker by **--env-file** parameter. You should ignore the text file when summit to SVN or git.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass the required variables as environment variables as in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env) or `-e` with [command line](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/)?